# JavaFX - ProviderNotFoundException: Provider not found

Tags: java, javafx, nio

I am building my JavaFX application together with the required JVM (openjdk-18.0.2.1) components using in jlink.
The build script is almost no different from being created using IDEA by default.

```
import org.gradle.internal.os.OperatingSystem

plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.13'
    id 'org.beryx.jlink' version '2.25.0'
}

group 'com.prototype'
version '1.0'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

ext {
    junitVersion = '5.9.0'
}

java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion.set(JavaLanguageVersion.of(18))
    }
    //withSourcesJar()
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}

application {
    mainModule = 'com.prototype.catassistant'
    mainClass = 'com.prototype.catassistant.CatAssistantApplication'
}

javafx {
    version = '18.0.1'
    modules = ['javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml', 'javafx.web']
}

dependencies {

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains/annotations
    implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations:23.0.0'

    implementation('org.controlsfx:controlsfx:11.1.1')

    // https://www.benf.org/other/cfr/api/index.html
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.benf/cfr
    implementation 'org.benf:cfr:0.152'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.9.1'

    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:${junitVersion}")
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:${junitVersion}")
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

jlink {
    imageZip = project.file("${buildDir}/distributions/app-${javafx.platform.classifier}.zip")
    options = ['--strip-debug', '--compress', '2', '--no-header-files', '--no-man-pages']
    jpackage {
        def currentOs = OperatingSystem.current()
        def imgType = currentOs.windows ? 'ico' : currentOs.macOsX ? 'icns' : 'png'
        icon = "src/main/resources/java.$imgType"
        if (currentOs.windows) {
            installerOptions += ['--win-per-user-install', '--win-dir-chooser', '--win-menu', '--win-shortcut', '--vendor', 'Prototype']
            imageOptions += ['--win-console',/* '--icon', 'src/main/resources/icon.ico'*/]
        }
    }
    launcher {
        name = 'CatAssistant'
    }
}

jlinkZip {
    group = 'distribution'
}
```

After building the image, I successfully run it and it works, but when it comes to working with jar files, I get an incomprehensible error: java.nio.file.ProviderNotFoundException: Provider not found
**Everything works fine from IDEA**. I am also confused by the fact that after the build, "(Unknown Source)" is written in the entire stacktrace instead of lines of code, if there is such a possibility, I would like to fix it.

```
Caused by: java.nio.file.ProviderNotFoundException: Provider not found
        at java.base/java.nio.file.FileSystems.newFileSystem(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.nio.file.FileSystems.newFileSystem(Unknown Source)
        at com.prototype.catassistant@1.0/com.prototype.catassistant.helper.FileHelper.readJarFile(Unknown Source)
```

`FileHelper#readJarFile`

```
    // https://stackoverflow.com/a/37413531/10663941
    public static void readJarFile(JarFile jar) {
        try (FileSystem system = FileSystems.newFileSystem(jar.getPath())) { // <- exception
            for (Path directory : system.getRootDirectories()) {
                try (Stream<Path> stream = Files.walk(directory)) {
                    stream.filter(Predicate.not(Files::isDirectory))
                            .forEach(path -> jar.addEntry(path, read(system.getPath(path.toString()))));
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            AlertUtil.showExceptionDialog(ex);
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }
```

I need help in solving this problem

Comment: Check if the [`jdk.zipfs`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/jdk.zipfs/module-summary.html) module is being included in your linked run-time image. If not, try to force include it with `--add-modules` (or a `requires` directive, though it's supposedly not recommended for an application module to require a provider module). As for the "unknown source" stuff, that comes from the `--strip-debug` option when linking the run-time image. That makes the image smaller, which is good for final deployment, but you lose debugging information such as source file names and line numbers.

Comment: Try updating your module-info.java to [`require jdk.zipfs`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/jdk.zipfs/module-summary.html), which is the file system provider used to access the jar resources.  Then jlink will likely include it in the generated image and it will work.  Alternately, you could choose the jlink option `--bind-services`, but that might pull in too many unnecessary modules.  Here is the [module-info](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk18/blob/6dae52f8e3993d529033147de8e34ad1e7d48c53/src/jdk.zipfs/share/classes/module-info.java) from the provider.

Comment: *Disclaimer, I haven't actually tried my suggestions ;-).

Comment: Alternate [resource lookup using spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70995461/get-a-list-of-files-from-a-classpath-resource-folder/70996955#70996955) or a pre-built index, but that it more complicated and would require spring 6 for modularity, so perhaps better to get your current approach to work.

Comment: @Slaw and @jewelsea Thank you very much. Solve - `require jdk.zipfs` and remove `--strip-debug` option from jlink settings. I have not worked with the module system before, so I have another problem in that area, if it doesn't bother you, can I ask for your help again? https://stackoverflow.com/q/73590370/10663941

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### ProviderNotFoundException

Most likely the `java.nio.file.ProviderNotFoundException` error is caused by the [`jdk.zipfs`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/jdk.zipfs/module-summary.html) module not being included in the run-time image created by `jlink` / `jpackage`<sup>**1**</sup>. That module is a "provider module" for the [`java.nio.file.FileSystemProvider`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/spi/FileSystemProvider.html) SPI. As such, I suspect none of the other modules that are part of your application directly or indirectly require the `jdk.zipfs` module. Typically, modules do not `requires` provider modules, as that defeats the purpose of the `uses` / `provides` mechanism of the *Java Platform Module System* (see the links in the second solution below for an explanation).

There are three ways you can fix this:

1. Use `--bind-services` when invoking `jlink`. This will cause `jlink` to look at all the required modules to see if any of them `uses` an SPI. If they do, then it will look for all available modules which `provides` implementations of the SPI and include them. Unfortunately, this will cause a lot of other modules to be included in your custom run-time image that you don't necessarily need.
2. Modify your module-info descriptor to add a `requires jdk.zipfs` directive. However, as noted in [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ServiceLoader.html), having an "application module" require a "provider module" is [not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73422270/6395627).
3. Include an `--add-modules jdk.zipfs` argument when invoking `jlink`. This will force `jlink` to include the `jdk.zipfs` module without the unfortunate side-effects of the previous two solutions. Personally, I recommend using this solution in your case.

### Unkown Source

The "Unknown Source" bits in the stack trace are caused by the `--strip-debug` argument which, unsurprisingly, removes debugging information from the byte-code. That includes the source file names and line numbers. Having `--strip-debug` reduces the size of the compiled code, which is good for the deployment version of your application.

---

<sup>**1.** You've [confirmed this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73587338/javafx-providernotfoundexception-provider-not-found#comment129952622_73587338).</sup>