# Can not open Windows-MY keystore when using jpackage

Tags: java, windows, javafx, keystore, jpackage

**Problem:**

Using JPackage to create an executable for Windows does not work with KeyStore. It returns an error.

**Code:**

```
KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY");
```

will throw exception:

```
java.security.KeyStoreException: Windows-MY not found
  at java.base/java.security.KeyStore.getInstance(Unknown Source)
 ...
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Windows-MY KeyStore not available
  at java.base/sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(Unknown Source) at java.base/java.security.Security.getImpl(Unknown Source)
```

Running the jpackage for Windows and trying to execute `KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY");` returns the error above.

Running the application in the IDE without JPackage works fine.

Comment: Which Java version, and which distributor (e.g. Oracle, Eclipse Adoptium, etc) are you using, and which Windows version? I guess it is missing a module. At a guess, you may need to add `requires jdk.crypto.mscapi;` to your `module-info.java` or otherwise ensure it is included by jpackage.

Comment: Thanks, this is the problem, I just added the module jdk.crypto.mscapi and it works. In my case, I've added this way: "--add-modules javafx.controls,jdk.crypto.mscapi". Can you answer the question with these details? Maybe it will help others.

Comment: Not a duplicate, but here are some similar Q&A's for posterity: [JavaFX - ProviderNotFoundException: Provider not found](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73587338/6395627) and [JavaFX - SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure \[duplicate\]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73590370/6395627) (and its duplicates).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The support for the Windows-MY keystore is part of the module `jdk.crypto.mscapi`. I guess this doesn't get included with your current setup through `jpackage`. I don't have much experience with modules, but I guess you need to add `requires jdk.crypto.mscapi;` to your module-info.java, or - as you mentioned in the comments - add it to the `jpackage` command line with `--add-modules` (e.g. `--add-modules jdk.crypto.mscapi`).

Comment: Given `jdk.crypto.mscapi` is likely a "provider module", the most appropriate solution is using `--add-modules` in the`jlink` / `jpackage` command, compared to using a `requires` directive in your module-info descriptor. The `ServiceLoader` documentation recommends that an "application module" should never require a "provider module". The other option is to use `--bind-services`, but that is likely to pull in way more modules than actually needed.