# "No jar file system provider found" trying to create a shrink Java image with jdeps and jlink for running Minecraft

Tags: java, jar, minecraft, jlink, jdeps

I'm trying to create a shrink Java image for running the Minecraft 1.20.1 client using `jdeps` and `jlink` (i.e. with only the minimum Java modules required to run Minecraft), however I'm running into errors and I would appreciate some guidance. This is what i did:

I downloaded the libraries listed in the [1.20.1 manifest](https://piston-meta.mojang.com/v1/packages/cdad018fbbe4e10919b560da3d1640d7b6355dbf/1.20.1.json) into my ~/.minecraft/libraries and the `client.jar` in ~/.minecraft/versions/1.20.1/1.20.1.jar.

To find the Java modules used by the Minecraft client, I ran:

```bash
jdeps \
    -q \
    --ignore-missing-deps \
    --print-module-deps \
    --multi-release 17 \
    -cp $HOME'/.minecraft/libraries/*' \
    --recursive \
    $HOME/.minecraft/versions/1.20.1/1.20.1.jar
```

which gives me:

```bash
java.base,java.compiler,java.desktop,java.management,java.naming,java.rmi,java.scripting,java.security.jgss,java.sql,jdk.jfr,jdk.unsupported
```

Then I passed those modules to `jlink` as `$modules`:

```bash
jlink --no-header-files --compress=2 --no-man-pages --add-modules $modules --output 'custom-jre'
```

Finally, I ran the Minecraft client as usual, but now with my newly created shrink JVM

```bash
/path/to/custom-jre/bin/java \
    -cp '<whole-list-of-minecraft-jars>' \
    net.minecraft.client.main.Main \
    --version 1.20.1 \
    --gameDir $HOME/.minecraft \
    --accessToken <auth-token>
```

Crashing with the error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:83)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No jar file system provider found
        at ac.o(SourceFile:101)
        at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:403)
        at ac.<clinit>(SourceFile:101)
        ... 1 more
```

So as you can see, the client started succesfully, but there is an unhandled exception at some point in the Minecraft source code.

Using [MCP](https://github.com/Hexeption/MCP-Reborn) (a decompiled version of the Minecraft source code) I managed to find the relevant piece of code that was throwing the error:

```java
// src/main/java/net/minecraft/Util.java

public class Util {
   // ....

   public static final FileSystemProvider ZIP_FILE_SYSTEM_PROVIDER = FileSystemProvider.installedProviders().stream().filter((p_201865_) -> {
      return p_201865_.getScheme().equalsIgnoreCase("jar");
   }).findFirst().orElseThrow(() -> {
      return new IllegalStateException("No jar file system provider found");
   });

   // ....
}
```

I'm not very familiar with Java file systems, but it basically can't find the "jar" file system provider. I wrote this minimal piece of code to illustrate the problem:

```java
import java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (var provider : FileSystemProvider.installedProviders()) {
            System.out.println(provider.getScheme().toString());
        }
    }
}
```

```bash
# Running with the system's JDK 17.0.8 (~259M)
$ java Test
file
jar
jrt

# Running it with my custom JRE: (~58M)
$ /path/to/custom-jre/bin/java Test
file
jrt # <- doesn't have the jar file system
```

The method I described here has worked with every project I have, it's only Minecraft that causes this issue. If there is a better approach I'd be happy to see it!

So what would be the appropriate solution for this? Am I missing something? Where is that "jar file system" defined? Any help is welcome, thanks in advance :)

Comment: Near-dupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73587338/javafx-providernotfoundexception-provider-not-found

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add module `jdk.zipfs` to your list, that should provide zip Filesystem.

Also see [jdk.zipfs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/jdk.zipfs/module-summary.html) docs and check whether `jdeps` helps you narrow down any more dependencies.

**UPDATE**

You appear to have used `jdeps` correctly to analyse module dependencies, but unfortunately it isn't able to help for dynamic code dependency such as based on reflection, services or other class loading.

You can use `jdeps` without the summary dependencies `--print-module-deps` to print a more detailed list such which might give a hint at service providers in packages inside the dependent modules - such as `java.nio.file.spi` shown here:

```
jdeps .....  your.jar
your.jar -> java.base
   ...
   some.module.name     -> java.nio.file.spi      java.base
```

You might find the provider name by searching on the package names in the JDK documentation linked above. Then you can use an option for `jlink` to suggest missing service provider implementation such as `java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider`:

```
jlink --suggest-providers java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider

Suggested providers:
  java.base provides java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider used by java.base
  jdk.zipfs provides java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider used by java.base
```

Another missing provider which often causes jlink packaging issues is where code needs additional charset support:

```
jlink --suggest-providers java.nio.charset.spi.CharsetProvider
Suggested providers:
   jdk.charsets provides java.nio.charset.spi.CharsetProvider used by java.base
```

Comment: Thanks! It is working like a charm now. The docs didn't help on how to make jdeps to detect `jdk.zipfs` sadly, I will continue researching that.